# Intellij IDEA - git ssh - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh, bitbucket

I am not able to clone a repository from Intellij IDEA and fails with the below error, shown in the image.

[image]

However, I am able to clone the repository from command prompt successfully, shown in the below image.

Note that I have added the public key file to the Bitbucket successfully. Also, the below image shows the contents of the 'config' file as well.

[image]

As suggested in the comments, I have run the `which git` command and it points to the location `/usr/local/bin/git` as shown in the below image:

[image]

Also, IntelliJ's settings for 'Version Control' > Git also points to the same location i.e.,  `/usr/local/bin/git` as shown in the below image:

[image]

I have also provided the **Intellij console tab error details** in the below image:

[image]

Comment: Could you please run `which git` in terminal and then check what executable do you have setup in Preferences | Version Control | Git? There is a chance that you may have different executables specified.
Also have you tried to restart an IDE once you've configured SSH keys? (It will help us to eliminate an issue with env. variables inheritance)

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov Thanks for your response, I have run the `which git` command and provided the results/images above. Indeed, both cmd prompt and Intellij Git settings are pointing to the same git location i.e.,`/usr/local/bin/git`. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

I had exactly the same problem recently using SSH as authentication method.
The solution for me was to create a `config` file inside `~/.ssh` (or modify it, if you already have one).

Inside this `config` file add:

```
Host github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/name_of_your_private_key
```

Then `chmod 600` to the `config` file.

Of course you can replace `Host` and `User` with values according to any particular case.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Your `IdentityFile` option solved me a long-standing issue with my Windows installation. Many thanks!

Comment: Great, same for me!

Answer (score 1):

Open the [Console tab of the Version control window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html#66741f93) in order to see what command is launched, and its full error message.

Regarding SSH URL, relaunch IntelliJ IDEA [after exporting](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use#comment1395424_912281):

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
```

You will see in that console tab much more details regarding the clone attempt and its errors.

Comment: I'd like to correct you a bit, if you don't mind:
1. in terms of Git - IDE relies on command-line Git and SSH settings inside IDE won't affect Git configuration. First and foremost what should be cheked - does git work in command-line? And then we need to check env. variable, whether IDE has an access to them and hasn't been started before SSH being configured.

2. Now IDE use Native SSH, a checkbox was available in older version

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov Is there any log associated to those operations?

Comment: could you please clarify what do you mean? Do I understand correctly that you would like to see what git commands are executed? If so, you can find it under "console" tab in "Git" toolwindow.

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html#66741f93, exactly. i have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot. Also I wanted to say that I really appreciate that you answer to questions related to IntelliJ IDEA.  Regarding first apart - "Check IDE SSH Configuration" it's also not that relevant since in case of Git operations, IDE ignores these settings, so you can delete it.

Comment: @VonC Thanks for your answer, I tried the command and relaunched Intellj, but it did not work. Do I need to relaunch Intellij from command prompt? Also, I have updated the question with the error details from Intellij's console tab (Image is provided towards the end in the question above). Thanks.

Comment: "Do I need to relaunch Intellij from command prompt": yes, to inherit the exported variable.